# How can we create a 10 hr mp3 by looping 1 hr mp3 using Python?

Tags: python, audio, automation, mp3

At the moment, I use audacity to do it. However, I have 100s of such mp3 files which is needed.
I was wondering if we can do it in Python?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:/Users/s/Desktop/free/1.mp3")

# Concatenation
times = sound + sound + sound + sound + sound + sound 

# writing mp3 files is a one liner
times.export("C:/Users/s/Desktop/free/mp_1.mp3", format="mp3")
```

I tried this approach , but it fails if I try to add 5  1 hr mp3s. I wanna have a generic method, is this do-able in python?

Comment: I would just use `ffmpeg` and the `stream_loop` option to loop the input N times into the output. No need for Python.

Comment: How can we do it? @vaizki A sample of that would be great. Also, 100+ files, how?